# How does Lorca kill the Klingons on Corvan 2 in The Butcher's Knife Cares not for the Lamb's Cry?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, captain-lorca

In [Star Trek Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Discovery) [S1:E4](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/tv/star_trek_discovery/s01/e04) *[The Butchers Knife Cares Not for the Lamb's Cry](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Butcher%27s_Knife_Cares_Not_for_the_Lamb%27s_Cry_(episode))* we see the Discovery receiving a distress call from Corvan 2, a mining planet that's under attack by Klingons.

Corvan 2 is a chief dilithium producer for Starfleet, and no other ships are close enough to help, so Lorca decides to use the experimental spore drive of his ship and zip right over.

There, Lorca commands the ship to kill the Klingons and save the Colony. It's not clear whether he fires phasers or uses another weapon.

Indeed, one commentator [writes](https://twitter.com/picards__fish/status/918659891262136320):

> How did Lorca kill the klingons? Drop a bomb n spore away or was it effects of spore drive?

My question is: **How does Lorca kill the Klingons on Corvan 2 in *The Butcher's Knife Cares not for the Lamb's Cry?***

Comment: I cannot find an image on line but rewatching the episode on Netflicks ( in the UK) it's clear that Lorca gives the order jump, Discovery then jumps away and a cluster of bombs/mines are left behind to detonate and destroy the birds of prey.

Comment: Thanks @Sarriesfan could you please expand that into an answer?

Comment: I could but there is no proof I an offer other than my own eyes.

Comment: In a TV based forum, that counts as sufficient evidence

Comment: @Sarriesfan is Netflix marketed as "Netflicks" in the UK?

Comment: @125748 no that's a mistake on my behalf, it's Netflixs here too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Hawkeye has requested me to answer I'll write one down.

In the Corvan 2 defense sequence of the episode "The But her Knife Cares not for the Lamb's Cry" it's clear that the USS Discovery leaves a cluster of devices behind when it jumps out on its spore drive to destroy the Klingon Birds of Prey.

In the sequence USS Discovery jumps in and destroys the first two birds of prey using its phasers.
 Captain Lorca orders a full stop and the ship sits still in the atmosphere over the colony absorbing Klingon fire depleting its shields.

Captain Lorca waits until the Birds of Prey are close enough for his plan to work, when he judges that they are close enough he makes the statement " Let's leave our Klingon friends a message they won't forget" and give the order " And Go".

The Discovery then enters a spore jump and once it has jumped we see briefly for 1-2 seconds 5 metallic looking devices left behind which explode destroying the Klingon ships.

<sup>Images from Star Trek Discovery (S01E04) - The Butchers Knife Cares Not for the Lambs Cry</sup>

[image]
<sup>40:21 - Discovery 'spores' out of there.</sup>

[image]
<sup>40:23 - Bombs left behind.</sup>

[image]
<sup>40:24 - Bombs explode.</sup>

[image]
<sup>40:25 - Wider shot of explosion a second later showing Klingon Warbird being engulfed.</sup>

Comment: I can only think that scene was to show that Lorca really is a nutter and Klingons are just very daft. The Klingons were hammering Discovery playing possum just fine before getting so close to it for Discovery's semi-suicidal plan to work.

Comment: Yes it was not a very good plan, Discovery destroyed 2 Klingon ships with its first phaser volley, it should have just kept on firing.

Comment: I've added some confirmation images to your answer.

Comment: @Jeeped thank you very much.